# OpenSSL decrypt return false

Tags: java, php

I tried to encrypt password in Java and decrypt it in PHP using OpenSLL. I get nothing but `bool(false)`.

Here is my Java code:

```
private String encryptAES(String text) throws Exception
{
    String key = "something-random";
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());

    String encrypttext = Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP);

    Log.v("ENCRYPTED", encrypttext); // 6sAfStQJ2zNUJLdRgXZsTA==

    return encrypttext;
}
```

Trying to decrypt the password in PHP:

```
$output = openssl_decrypt("6sAfStQJ2zNUJLdRgXZsTA==", "AES-256-ECB", "something-random");
var_dump($output); // bool(false)
```

With given error from openSLL:

```
error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
```

Does anybody know whats wrong? I've tried to look for the error, but everything is about node.js

---

Based on @RandomSeed 's answer I changed PHP code to following:

```
$output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode("6sAfStQJ2zNUJLdRgXZsTA=="), "AES-256-ECB", "something-random");
```

Which leads to error:

```
error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
```

This edited decrypt function also returns `bool(false)`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @basti12354 no, went different way...

Comment: Could you tell us which way you went ;) Have been searching/trying this thing for 2 days... At the moment I am using mcrypt which is not the best...(but running)

Comment: @basti12354 sorry for late response, but I cant. I have no longer access to that project...

Answer (score 0):

Your `encrypttext` string was Base64-encoded after being AES-encrypted. You need to [`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) your input string before decrypting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doe's not work. Please see edited question.

Comment: @kikinet the `=` signs at the end of your base64-encoded string indicates the original AES-encrypted string was padded. You might need to trim trailing spaces before decrypting.

Comment: I removed both `=` signs from the string. And it gives me the same error as before: `wrong final block length`